# How to navigate between pages based on the api output in app start in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, navigation

On first time app launch, Call API and based on api output eg: IsLoginRequired=true ==>Navigate to LoginPage else Navigate to WelcomePage
On second time app launch navigate to Welcomepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an intermediate Page where you will call API and on that page you can decide which page to show.

OR

You can use Application.Current.Properties to store whether user has logged in or not

Whenever user login is successful store IsUserLoggedIn property to as below

```
Application.Current.Properties ["IsUserLoggedIn"] = true;
```

if user fails to login

```
Application.Current.Properties ["IsUserLoggedIn"] = true;
```

And you can check whether is user logged in or not as below

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("IsUserLoggedIn"))
{
    var IsUserLoggedIn = Application.Current.Properties ["IsUserLoggedIn"] as bool;
   if(IsUserLoggedIn){
      //already logged in show welcome page
   } 
   else{
       //show login page
   }
} 
else{
   //show login page
}
```

Comment: Thank u for ur reply, Application.Current.Properties ["IsUserLoggedIn"] = loginvalue; How to set that loginvalue by calling api on app launch. If I take   hardcoded value it is working, but my requirement is i have decide IsUserLoggedIn value based on api output.

Answer (score 0):

You can either check in the App constructor if the user is logged in, and then navigate to the WelcomePage from the LoginPage after a successful login:

```
public App ()
{
    if (IsLoginRequired) {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage (new LoginPage ());
    } else {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage (new WelcomePage ());
    }
}
```

Or you can also always navigate to the WelcomePage and the WelcomePage checks if the user needs to log in first and then displays the LoginPage modally and pop it after a successful login:

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());
```

and

```
await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for ur reply, IsLoginRequired=true or false is based on the api output. I am calling api in oncreate(). IsLoginRequired value is decided by API. How to call API on app start.

Comment: What kind of API are you talking about?